# Partitions on GPT disk are not in the recommended order?

Tags: windows-8, installation, partitioning, windows-installation, gpt

I want to install a clean RTM Windows 8.0 on a laptop that came with OEM Windows 8.0 pre-installed. I have a working ISO image on DVD. The problem is that the setup program complains about "recommended order" for a GPT disk.

> The partitions on the disk selected for installation are not in the
>   recommended order. For additional information about installing to GPT
>   disks go to the Microsoft website (www.microsoft.com) and search for
>   GPT.
>
> Do you want to proceed with installation?

I can obviously select to ignore it and install anyway! But what does it mean? What will the consequences be if I select to continue? Will I loose any partition?

**Screenshots**

[image: a]
[image: b]
[image: c]
[image: d]

**Update**

---

I ignored the warning, or whatever you want to call that, and Windows 8.0 installed successfully. No partitions were lost in the process. You can see that by the screenshot below.

[image: e]

You can also see that the partition layout is the same as before. In other words partitions have not been moved and reordered to fit the ideal GPT partition order as described by MS articles posted by Rod in the answer below.

Comment: Provide information about the partitions so we can do some research

Comment: OK, I will upload a screemshot. Just have to reboot into Wondows. Sadly I can't share the photo right through the SE app on my Android device.

Comment: @Ramhound Screenshots added. What can you tell me about these xxx MB partitions? Why are there so many partitions on a laptop computer? There are 7 different partitions (!!!). I know I only created the HEK_DATA partition, all the rest came with the computer.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but more info is here: CTRL+F "Order" http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824839.aspx

Comment: @ta.speot.is OK, thanks! But if I compare my screenshots, to that diagram, I can see that it clearly follows the order: WINRE, System, MSR, Windows. It might be complaining about that 350 MB "recovery" partition in front of my DATA partition, and the "RECOVERY" OEM partition?...

Comment: That article still doesn't say what happens if you proceed and you select to ignore it and continue with the installation anyway...

Comment: I ignored the warning, or whatever you want to call that, and Windows 8.0 installed successfully. No partitions were lost in the process.

Comment: Windows 10 also complains about this (after following a Microsoft article on how to create the partitions manually). It seems that the windows installer and some technet articles disagree with eachother.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft has some documents that describe how Windows works with EFI and expects partitions to be laid out:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744301%28WS.10%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463525.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh824839.aspx
- (Probably others that I don't happen to have bookmarked.)

The bottom line is that Microsoft expects certain partitions to be present in a certain order. Deviating from Microsoft's expectations is not necessarily an error, but it will make the installer squawk, as you've seen. Deviations can cause problems down the line in certain cases. For instance, consider the following placement for the [EFI System Partition (ESP):](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition)

- OS #1 Partition
- ESP
- OS #2 Partition

Suppose you then want to remove OS #2 and give its space to OS #1. The ESP will sit in the way, complicating this expansion. It  can still be done, and in several ways; but it would be easier if the ESP were the first partition on the disk.

There can also be more Windows-specific issues with the Windows reserved partition, which Windows partitioning tools can use when resizing partitions.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any other OS or document that you want to keep on this HD? Because for a clean installation of windows you may delete all partitions and install the new OS. The Windows Installation will create the necessary partitions and all will run perfectly.

Edit: Awnser your question.. since your laptop came with OEM Windows 8.0 the manufacturer create some partitions like Recovery (of the OS Installation and drivers), etc. The other partitions that have less then 1GB are from Windows Installation like Recovery (of the system), MSR (Microsoft Reserved Partition), and so on. It's normal the laptop that came with OEM OS came with all those partitions.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You can post this as a comment. This question is concerned with the issue of "recommended order".

Comment: I see you have edited the answer now. Can you please move this answer to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/734259/how-to-install-rtm-windows-8-on-a-laptop-with-oem-windows-8) instead?

Comment: Sorry, but since I don't have 50 reputation I cannot post a comment.

Comment: Sure! Doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all other partitions, except the largest primary storage partition and the second largest recovery partition. The installer did not complain and was able to create the required partitions itself.